# Getting Command line in Python

Tags: python, bash, command-line

So I am working on this project where I take input from the user (a file name ) and then open and check for stuff. the file name is "cur"
Now suppose the name of my file is `kb.py` (Its in python)
If I run it on my terminal then first I will do:
python kb.y and then there will a prompt and user will give the input. 
I'll do it this way:

```
A = raw_input("Enter File Name: ")
b = open(A, 'r+')
```

I dont want to do that. Instead i want to use it as a command for example:
**python kb.py cur** and it will take it as an input and save to a variable which then will open it.
I am confused how to get a input in the same command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `sys.argv`, like this:

```
import sys

# this part executes when the script is run from the command line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2: # check for the correct number of arguments
        print 'usage: python kb.py cur'
    else:
        call_your_code(sys.argv[1]) # first command line argument
```

Note: `sys.argv[0]` is the script's name, and `sys.argv[1]` is the first command line argument. And so on, if there were more arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help but can you please explain what if __name__ == '__main__': and call_your_code(sys.argv[1]) is doing ?

Comment: @Nick First question: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Second question: that's the part where your program starts, the part where you're going to use the `cur` argument. It's up to you to decide what to do here!

Comment: Ok that helps. Just one more question that suppose I enter python kb.py cur and Now I have to open cur file to see whats in it then how can I assign it to a variable. I mean where exactly is it getting assigned in the above mentioned code, is there any particular variable on which I can call open(VAR, 'r+')

Comment: A = raw_input("Enter File Name: ")
B =open(call_your_code, 'r+') I am doing something like this in python

Comment: No, the value of `argv[1]` is just the text you entered from the command line. If you executed your program like this: `python kb.py cur` then in `argv[1]` you'll have the string `'cur'`. It's up to you to decide what to do with this from this point on, for example, opening a file called `'cur'`, etc. The command line arguments are simply text.

Answer (score 0):

For simply stuff `sys.argv[]` is the way to go, for more complicated stuff, have a look at the [argparse-module](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbose:
   print "verbosity turned on"
```

output:

```
$ python prog.py --verbose
verbosity turned on
$ python prog.py --verbose 1
usage: prog.py [-h] [--verbose]
prog.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 1
$ python prog.py --help
usage: prog.py [-h] [--verbose]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --verbose   increase output verbosity
```